# Javascript - Properties in functions in objects reverting to newest created object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a problem. Whenever I try to create an object of the Candy function, all the attributes seem to be created fine. But, whenever I attempt to run the draw function, all of the properties of the newest created object are used, instead of the one I am using. It will always draw the second object that I created twice, but never the first one. I have no idea why. I have tried everything to try to fix this, so if something seems highly inefficient in this code, it was probably one of the many attempts of me trying to fix this. Do you guys know the problem?

Here is the code for the Candy function:

```js
Candy = function(img, location, canvas) {
 self = {}
 self.image = new Image()
 self.image.src = img
 self.location = {x: location.x, y: location.y}
 self.canvas = canvas
 self.draw = function() {
  self.canvas.drawImage(self.image, self.location.x, self.location.y, 132.4, 132.4)
 }
 self.move = function(FPS, seconds, location) {
  frames = FPS * seconds
  deltaX = (location.x - self.location.x) / frames
  deltaY = (location.y - self.location.y) / frames
  counter = 0
  setInterval(function() {
   self.location.x += deltaX
   self.location.y += deltaY
   counter++
   self.draw()
   if(counter >= frames)
    clearInterval()
  }, 1000 / FPS)
 }
 self.image.onload = function() {
  Candy.list.push(self)
  Candy.queue.splice(0, 1)
  
  if(Candy.queue.length == 0)
   draw()
  else
   Candy(Candy.queue[0].img, Candy.queue[0].location, Candy.queue[0].canvas)
 }
}
Candy.list = []
Candy.queue = []
```

Here is where I call the Candy function:

```js
gameStarted = true
 Candy.queue.push({img: "client/img/candy.png", location: {x: width / 3 - 87.5, y: height / 10}, canvas: canvasContext})
 Candy.queue.push({img: "client/img/candy2.png", location: {x: width / 3 - 87.5, y: 3 * (height / 10)}, canvas: canvasContext})
 
 Candy(Candy.queue[0].img, Candy.queue[0].location, Candy.queue[0].canvas)
```

Finally, here is the draw function:

```js
function draw() {
 colorRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 'white');
 colorText("Player 1", 0.02, 0.05, "black", "40px Comic Sans");
 colorText("Player 2", 0.88, 0.05, "black", "40px Comic Sans");
 
 if(!gameStarted) {
  if(player1.ready)
   colorText("Ready", 0.02, 0.09, "green", "20px Comic Sans");
  else
   colorText("Not Ready", 0.02, 0.09, "red", "20px Comic Sans");
  if(player2.ready)
   colorText("Ready", 0.88, 0.09, "green", "20px Comic Sans");
  else
   colorText("Not Ready", 0.88, 0.09, "red", "20px Comic Sans");
  if(player1.ready && player2.ready)
   colorText("Press a button to start the game!", 0.32, 0.5, "black", "40px Comic Sans")
 }else{
  alert(Candy.list[0].image.src)
  alert(Candy.list[0].getImg())
  for(var i = 0; i < Candy.list.length; i++) {
   Candy.list[i].draw()
  }
  //TODO
 }
}
```

Comment: You should consider moving `move` and `draw` from a property on `self` (rather `this`, since you've already figured out the problem.) to `Candy.prototype`. That way, all `Candy`s will share a reference rather than having their own copy of those functions.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. In the function, I replaced self with this and it fixed the issue. No need for any replies.